# unable to resolve host

Tags: vnc

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi to my macbook air and when I run the command vncserver :1

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.
```

it also says cannot resolve host when I use get apt- functions. Can you please provide some insight. Ive looked through the archives here but nothing is really helping

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **recent version of MAC OSX** then it is very simple.

Go to the **finder->go->connect to server** 
[image]

A new window will open and type the server address as `vnc://192.168.1.8:5901`

`5091` is the no of port the Raspberry PI vnc server is listening to.
Hit connect and enter the password "**raspberry**"-default password.

[image]

you will be connected and see a PI Desktop.

or

---

Try running `vncviewer` from command line.

Comment: I tried and my mac gave me an error:           Connection failed to “192.168.1.102:5901”. Please make sure that Screen Sharing (in the Sharing section of System Preferences) is enabled on the computer to which you are attempting to connect. Also make sure your network connection is working properly.

Comment: Have VNC server running on Raspberry PI? If not start vnc server using ssh.

Comment: I used the code here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc/installing-vnc  and it that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: It should have worked then!
Also did you try running `vncserver` or `tightvncserver` instead of `vncserver :1`on your raspberry PI?

Comment: Yes, I tried those as well and its giving me the same msg as above

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and it was due to an invalid hostname configured on my pi. My command prompt looked something like:

```
pi@(none) ~ $
```

I configured a valid hostname using `raspi-config` and it resolved the issue.
The command prompt should look something like:

```
pi@rpimpd2 ~ $
```